# How can I merge multiple unknown number of lists together?

Tags: python, list, append

Based on the number of time the for loop runs, I get multiple list. I want to merge all those list and make one list.

for example:

```
list = []

for i in item:
   list.append(i)
print(list)
```

How can I merge all the list I get to one list ?

Comment: What is item in this case? Do you think you could create a working example, showing the output that it gives as well as the desired output??

Comment: item could be any other list, doesn't matter. I am appending the values of i in a list and i keep getting the list and the number of list i get is unknown. So I want to merge all of them together at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If your item is list of lists, then you can use `extend` to achieve the same.

```
lst = []
    
for i in item:
   lst.append(i)

out = []
for sublist in lst:
    out.extend(sublist)

print(out)
```

Also, avoid using python keywords like `list` for the variable name, use something like lst instead.

Comment: not working for my use case.

Comment: So, actually its like I am keep getting the output in the form of list unitl for loop runs. So Its like I want to join all the output/lists and add into 1 list. Your solution doesn't seem to be working for that. Anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `list` as a variable name, it's a reserved word for python lists.

This code should work for you:

```
list_ = []
f_list = []

item = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in item:
    list_.append(i)
    f_list.extend(list_)
    print(list_)
print("Final list - ", f_list)
```

Output:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Final list -  [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```